# mule dataweave anypoint studio The prefix "metadata" for attribute "metadata:id" associated with an element type "dw:transform-message" is not bound

Tags: xml, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I'm getting this exception when running a mule application.

```
The prefix "metadata" for attribute "metadata:id" associated with an element type "dw:transform-message" is not bound.
```

It's calling out a dataweave transformation.  I've gotten similar error before, just after editing through the Configuration XML rather than Message Flow.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511445/mule-dataweave-transform-message-failing-with-missing-metadataid-attribute) which has a response about missing namespaces.  From what I can tell, I have the dataweave namespace though

```
xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" 
xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" 
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
```

I'm very new to mule, if I'm missing something in the namespace, or if someone has seen this, it would be appreciated. 
Here's the metadata:id too

```
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="json to flattened json" metadata:id="e1e281d5-880f-48f9-92af-b5ead2b0e5dd">
        <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
```

Comment: Did below answer helped you.If yes please accept the answer so others facing same issue could get benefit from it,please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the metadata-id

**`metadata:id="e1e281d5-880f-48f9-92af-b5ead2b0e5dd`**

from your config xml

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="json to flattened json" metadata:id="e1e281d5-880f-48f9-92af-b5ead2b0e5dd">
<dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
```

save it and re-start application once again.It should work.

Seems this got copied over from some other config xml file, when you were editing your config xml.

"metadata-id" is generated when you define your payload metadata in "Transform message" component using message flow.It remains valid for that particular config.When you copy this element to some other config it becomes obsolete/un-bound to that context.

Let us know if that resolves your issue.

Comment: That worked! I ended up having this issue on two transforms, but once I deleted the id from both, the application deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata"
```

in the mule tag

```
<mule xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata"/>
```